# Android: Share a Texture Between GLSurfaceViews in Separate EGL Contexts

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, egl

Each `GLSurfaceView` is constructed with its own EGLContext. Using the same context across multiple `GLSurfaceViews` to have access to the same textures seems to not work on across all GPUs (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675355/sharing-the-gles20-context-and-textures-between-different-glsurfaceviews)).

My question is whether there is a way to share a `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` texture across multiple `GLSurfaceViews` with their default, separate contexts. By default only the thread that creates the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` would be able to access the texture, but I am looking for a way to let the other threads in separate EGL contexts read from this texture, and then render to their separate `GLSurfaceViews`.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't share contexts between multiple GLSurfaceViews because the API doesn't provide a way to do so.  You can try to kluge it, but that's likely to break in unpleasant ways.  The best way to handle this is to use a plain SurfaceView.

Bear in mind that a GLSurfaceView is just a SurfaceView with some helper code that manages threading and EGL contexts.  If you don't mind writing that part (or just lifting it wholesale out of [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)) it can be much more convenient to work with SurfaceView.

To the other part of your question, it is possible to share an external texture across EGL contexts, but it's risky.  Grafika's "show + capture camera" Activity shares a GLSurfaceView context with a second context created for MediaCodec, and accesses the texture from both.  Unfortunately it does this incorrectly, leading to a race condition.  [A bug report](https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/36) explains the problem and a suggested solution, and has links to the EGL/GLES docs that specify the behavior when multiple contexts on separate threads share a texture.

FWIW, I haven't seen a GPU where the Activity in question simply didn't work, so I don't think there's a fundamental problem with sharing.  You just have to do the barriers correctly.  It's much easier to work with a single context though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Fadden! I was at first attempting to use `GLSurfaceViews` but the code was really messy, since there is no built-in API support for this. I'll go ahead with the ordinary `SurfaceView` approach. By the way, are you aware of any open source projects that do something similar (i.e. create an EGLContext with an orindary SurfaceView)? The most similar Grafika seems to offer is https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/HardwareScalerActivity.java

Comment: Grafika has multiple activities that render onto SurfaceView with GLES. I'd recommend just lifting the entire com.android.grafika.gles package; if you're working with external textures you'll probably want some of the other bits too. "texture from camera" and "record GL app" are other examples.